# How to parse a string into multiple variables when one part can have spaces?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a string that I need to split into four variables: cmd1, cmd2, id, address.

I have this:

```
string x = "ADD ADDRESS 001 21 PARKWAY DRIVE";
string cmd1, cmd2, id, address;
istringstream ss(x);

ss >> cmd1 >> cmd2 >> id >> address;
cout << cmd1 << endl << cmd2 << endl << id << endl << address;
```

The problem is that if the address input has a space in it, it will only take the input up to the first space, as stringstream does, so how would I get the entire address and store it into "address"?

Looking for this:

```
INPUT: ADD ADDRESS 001 21 PARKWAY DRIVE

STORED: 
cmd1 = ADD
cmd2 = ADDRESS
id = 001
address = 21 PARKWAY DRIVE
```

Right now, i'm getting this:

```
INPUT: ADD ADDRESS 001 21 PARKWAY DRIVE

STORED: 
cmd1 = ADD
cmd2 = ADDRESS
id = 001
address = 21
```

Perhaps there is a better method, other than stringstream to split up a string this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to read string until id:

```
ss >> cmd1 >> cmd2 >> id;
```

and then use getline for address:

```
getline(ss, address);
```

also to remove the extra space you can use a string function called substr or use ws:

```
address = address.substr(1,address.size()); or

ws(ss);
```

so your program will look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

string x = "ADD ADDRESS 001 21 PARKWAY DRIVE";
string cmd1, cmd2, id, address;
istringstream ss(x);

ss >> cmd1 >> cmd2 >> id;
ws(ss);
getline(ss, address);

cout << cmd1 << endl << cmd2 << endl << id << endl << address;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to do the job. It lets you to skip redundant spaces if needed, do some validation (e.g. accept only uppercase) etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    const std::string x = "ADD ADDRESS 001 21 PARKWAY DRIVE";

    const auto regex = std::regex(R"(^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.+)$)");
    std::smatch result;

    if (std::regex_match(x, result, regex)) {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < result.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline(ss, address)` to read the remainder of the line into `address`. You can also use `ss >> std::ws` first, to discard any leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
ss >> cmd1 >> cmd2 >> id;
getline(ss, address);
address = address.substr(1, address.size());
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: there is no function substring, its substr.

Comment: Yeah, i figured out that it was substr.

Comment: It was a very long time ago :)

Comment: @hasan83: It would be great if you could provide some explanation of your code.